# Can I combine tokenizers `trigram` and `icu_tokenizer` to search for fuzzy text as well as emojis in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using `elasticsearch_dsl` and have a field in question I'm searching:

```
content_text = Text(analyzer=document_analyzer)
```

and using the following document analyzer:

```
document_analyzer = analyzer(
    'document_analyzer',
    tokenizer=tokenizer('trigram', 'ngram', min_gram=3, max_gram=3),
    filter=['lowercase'],
)
```

This works great for finding `Management` when searching for `manage`, etc. But if the document text consists of an emoji (for example,  ) it doesn't find it. If I use a different tokenizer (and install the ICU Analyzer plugin):

```
document_analyzer = analyzer(
    'document_analyzer',
    tokenizer=tokenizer('icu_tokenizer'),
    filter=['lowercase'],
)
```

...then I can find the emoji just fine, but I lose the ability to use trigram searches, and `manage` no longer finds `Management`.
Is there a way to combine the tokenizers, or create a document analyzer that uses both methods for searching?

Comment: You ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @Yinci I did not.